# How do I get object with value I want in an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array with the following structure:

```
balance = [
    {id: 2, is_selected: true},
    {id: 4, is_selected: true},
    {id: 15, is_selected: false},
    {id: 137, is_selected: false},
    {id: 30, is_selected: false}
];
```

How do I get object like so:

```
selected = {2: true, 4: true, 15: false, 137: false, 30: false};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform your initial structure into key-value pairs and then convert those into an object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const balance = [
    {id: 2, is_selected: true},
    {id: 4, is_selected: true},
    {id: 15, is_selected: false},
    {id: 137, is_selected: false},
    {id: 30, is_selected: false}
];

const selected = Object.fromEntries(balance.map(({id,is_selected})=>([[id],is_selected])))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Yay, I got it. Thank you. :))